# Function can return many types of responses. How do I declare the type of the response in the function that receives the response?

Tags: typescript

With this class method

```
async openProject(
    fileName: string, 
    force: boolean, 
    progress: boolean
) {
    const response = await this.request({
        type: 'request',
        cmd: 'open_project',
        payload: { value: fileName, force: force, progress: progress }
    });

    return {
        id: response['payload']['project_id']
    };
}
```

I get the TypeScript warning when I try to access the payload property on response:

> [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no
>   index signature.

I am used to declaring types for parameters in function calls. But how should I declare the type for response in this case? `this.requests` returns a promise that can response in several different kinds of responses.

Should I perhaps:

- create a response type for each type of request and
- have `this.request` return a union of all response types

*EDIT:*

Here is a failed attempt of mine at a solution

```
export type CreateProjectResponse = {
    payload: {
        project_id: string;
    }
}

export type GetDevicesResponse = {
    payload: {
        devices: [];
    }
}

export type GenericResponse = GetDevicesResponse | CreateProjectResponse;

request(body: any) {
    const transactionId = this.newTransactionId();

    const requestMessage = JSON.stringify({
        ...body,
        trans_id: transactionId
    });

    if (this.logger) this.logger(requestMessage);

    return new Promise<GenericResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
        const timeoutTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            const timeoutMessage = 'Request timed out';
            if (this.logger) this.logger(timeoutMessage);
            reject(Error(timeoutMessage));
        }, this.maxTime);

        this.requestCallbacks[transactionId] = {
            resolver: resolve,
            rejecter: reject,
            timeoutTimer: timeoutTimer
        };
        this.socket.send(requestMessage);
    });
}

async createProject() {
    const response = await this.request({
        type: 'request',
        cmd: 'create_project',
    }) ;

    return {
        id: response['payload']['project_id']
    };
};

async getDevices() {
    const response = await this.request({
        type: 'request',
        cmd: 'get_devices',
    });

    return response['payload']['devices'].filter((device: DeviceResponse) => {
        return device['type'] === 'device';
    }).map((device: DeviceResponse) => {
        return {
            id: device['device_id'],
            name: device['name']
        };
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done with function overloading...

```
interface IRequest {
    type: 'request';
    cmd: 'create_project' | 'get_devices';
}

interface IResponse {
    id: string
}

interface CreateProjectRequest extends IRequest { cmd: 'create_project'; }
interface GetDevicesRequest extends IRequest { cmd: 'get_devices'; }

interface CreateProjectResponse extends IResponse { }
interface GetDevicesResponce extends IResponse { name: string }

function request(body: CreateProjectRequest) : CreateProjectResponse
function request(body: GetDevicesRequest) : GetDevicesResponce
function request<T extends IRequest>(body: T) : IResponse {
    return {} as IResponse;
}

var myCreateProjectResponse = request({ cmd: 'create_project', type: 'request' });
var myGetDevicesResponse = request({ cmd: 'get_devices', type: 'request' });
```

[[DEMO]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IRequest%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'request'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cmd%3A%20'create_project'%20%7C%20'get_devices'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IResponse%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20CreateProjectRequest%20extends%20IRequest%20%7B%20cmd%3A%20'create_project'%3B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20GetDevicesRequest%20extends%20IRequest%20%7B%20cmd%3A%20'get_devices'%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20CreateProjectResponse%20extends%20IResponse%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20GetDevicesResponce%20extends%20IResponse%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20request(body%3A%20CreateProjectRequest)%20%3A%20CreateProjectResponse%0D%0Afunction%20request(body%3A%20GetDevicesRequest)%20%3A%20GetDevicesResponce%0D%0Afunction%20request%3CT%20extends%20IRequest%3E(body%3A%20T)%20%3A%20IResponse%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%7D%20as%20IResponse%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20myCreateProjectResponse%20%3D%20request(%7B%20cmd%3A%20'create_project'%2C%20type%3A%20'request'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Avar%20myGetDevicesResponse%20%3D%20request(%7B%20cmd%3A%20'get_devices'%2C%20type%3A%20'request'%20%7D)%3B)

Comment: This was awesome

Answer (score 0):

you could try making `request` function generic:

```
function request<T = any>(): Promise<T> {
    //...
    return {} as Promise<T>;
}

interface MyData {
    prop: number;
}

async () => {
    const data = await request<MyData>();
    //data.prop - awailable in autocomplete
}
```

`T = any` sets the default type

you can find more info at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper solution would be to **use user defined type guards** for the different possible answer types.

Example :

```
    interface Project: {
     project_id: number
    }

    function isProject(data: any): data is TypeA {
      return data.hasOwnProperty 
        && data.hasOwnProperty(project_id)
        && typeof data.project_id === "number"
    }
```

This will allow to let typescript compile know that the data you received is indeed of the Project type.

```
    async openProject(
        fileName: string, 
        force: boolean, 
        progress: boolean
    ): number {
        const response = await this.request({
            type: 'request',
            cmd: 'open_project',
            payload: { value: fileName, force: force, progress: progress }
        });

        const payload = response.payload

        if (isProject(payload)) {
          return payload.project_id
        }
    }
```

You can deal with various types of results and should probably throw an exception if you don't succeed to validate the payload against a known type.

**Usefull links :**

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html

https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv

*A good way to implement type guards is to use a json schema library like ajv.*

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/03/26/typescript-data-validation/